# How to select text with touchpad without pressing the "hard" key?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad, unix

Now on OS X, when I want to select some text, I have to press the "hard" key on touchpad with thumb and drag through the text with another finger on touchpad. With linux on the same macbook pro, I could quickly touch the touchpad twice and start selection/dragging behavior without pressing the "hard" key on touchpad with single finger. I feel the way in linux is much easier for fingers and quicker. Is it possible to configure OS X touchpad behave in the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest thing available is the "Three finger drag" option in System prefs -- under trackpad you'll find the option to use it:

[image: Trackpad prefs]

This lets you drag by hold three fingers on the trackpad and dragging..

Comment: Is there any other way around without using three fingers? it is hard to select longer texts.

Answer (score 36):

The settings location where the three finger "drag" is enabled has changed over time.

From **OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" to macOS 10.14 "Mojave"**:

1. Go to System Preferences > Accessibility
2. Choose Mouse & Trackpad from the left options list
3. Click Trackpad Options
4. Tick "Enable dragging" and select “three finger drag” from the drop-down menu next to it

For **macOS 10.15 "Catalina" and later**:

1. Go to System Preferences > Accessibility
2. Choose Pointer Control
3. On the Mouse & Trackpad tab, click Trackpad Options
4. Tick "Enable dragging" and select “three finger drag” from the drop-down menu next to it

Comment: In macOS Catalina it's under Accessibility > Pointer Control > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Option

Answer (score 19):

Had this issue with new Macbook Air (latest one late 2015) and old trackpad that suddenly required a hard click and drag, simultaneously, to copy large amounts. Found that above directions with modest variation works perfectly as:

1. Go to System Preferences > Accessibility
2. Choose Mouse & Trackpad from the left options list
3. Click Trackpad Options
   Step #4 also works as:
4. Tick "enable dragging" and select "without drag lock" from the drop-down menu next to it

This was how my trackpad always worked before I migrated to the new computer, and it is easier on fingers. 1 finger, no hard pressure.

Comment: as for me, the most useful answer, just I needed "with drag lock" option :)
It's especially useful for screenshots (when you need to select some region on the screen with touchpad)
And of course, I set tap instead of hard click in System Preferences > Trackpad

Answer (score 6):

the way to do it in high sierra is to go to accessibility options, and then enable dragging and select the three finger drag as shown here.

Also note I had changed the app expose to 4 fingers from trackpad settings.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to system preferences > Trackpad
Trackpad > Point and Click Tap
Point and Click > Check "Tap to Click"

This will give you the behavior your want.

The are two methods for selecting text with tap to click enabled; the first is simplest to setup by just checking tap to click as outlined above; the second is my favorite setup but requires one more tweak in system preferences; the second will likely be your favorite too because you don't need to complete the selection in a single slide)

1. To select text (with drag-lock set to OFF in accessibility - the default):
   Tap & Slide (Finger Contact, Finger Lift, Finger Contact, Finger Slide, Finger Lift (The selection extent is finalized with the finger lift)
2. To select text (with drag-lock set to ON in accessibility):
   Tap & Slide & Tap (Finger Contact, Finger Lift, Finger Contact, Finger Slide, Finger Lift, Finger Contact, Finger Lift (The selection extent can be adjusted with multiple finger slides; the selected extent is finalized with the final finger tap)

To turn on Drag-Lock for the Trackpad:
Go to system preferences > Accessibility
Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad
Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options
Trackpad Options > Select "Enable Dragging"; Select "with Drag-Lock"

Cheers!

Comment: Selection with drag lock was what i was looking for, thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

[Serge Voloshenko](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/351185/serge-voloshenko)'s  [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151683/how-to-select-text-with-touchpad-without-pressing-the-hard-key#comment501731_235348) to a [different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/235348/32815) is what worked for me finally:

> In **macOS Catalina** it's under Accessibility > Pointer Control > Mouse &
> Trackpad > Trackpad Option

I prefer the dragging with drag lock option, but there's the three finger drag too:

[image]